# Likelihood Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose $Y_I$ is independent and identically distributed $N(0, σ^2)$, $i = 1, ..., n$. The estimand is $σ = \sqrt{Var(Y_1)}$. Derive the likelihood, sufficient statistic, and score of $\sigma$.

$$L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \Pi_{i=1}^n f(X_i | \mu, \sigma^2) $$

$$= \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(X_i-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$$
With $\mu$ = 0:
$$= \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(X_i)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

$$L(\sigma^2) =  \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2})^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i)^2/2\sigma^2}$$
Is it possible to just take the square root of this to get $\sigma$, not $\sigma^2$? I understand that once you get this far, you just take the derivative of the function to get the score.

For the SS, we look for two functions in the form of g($\mu ; T(\vec{x})$) and h(x).

$$(2\pi)^{-n/2} (\sigma)^{-n} e^{-1/2\sigma^2} e^{-\sum X_i^2}$$
Once here, though, I'm confused as to what is necessarily relevant in working with our $\sigma$. Can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: First, the score is defined as the derivative of the log of the likelihood, not the likelihood itself. (That should make calculations easier.) Second for the sufficient statistic, you mean $g(\sigma; T(x))$, right? Also you are factoring the likelihood (which you already calculated) into those 2 factors (your last expression doesnt equal your second-last expression).

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood is
$$
L(\sigma |X) = \frac{1}{( 2\pi )^{n/2}  \sigma^n } \exp\{ - 2^{-1}\sigma ^ {-2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\} .
$$
The minimal sufficient statisic is $ T(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 $.

The log-likelihood is
$$
l(\sigma)=-n/2 \ln(2 \pi) - n\ln \sigma -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2,
$$
and the "score" is
$$
l'(\sigma) = -\frac{n}{\sigma} + \frac{1}{\sigma^3}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2. 
$$

EDIT: 
$$
\operatorname{var}(l'(\sigma)) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \operatorname{var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2/\sigma^2 \right) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{(n)})=\frac{2n}{\sigma^2}.
$$

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much. Do you perhaps want to help me in deducing the variance of the score function? I'm a little confused as to what the Var(1\sigma) would be... or are we presuming sigma is now a constant?

Comment: You are welcome. (1) Please see the edited answer. (2) Variance of a constant is zero and in general $Var(aX+b) = a^2 Var(X)$. (3) You can upvote\accept the answer if it helps you.